# Are character names permanent? If I don't like mine, am I totally screwed?

Tags: starcraft-2

My first impulse was to pick my first name just to see if it was available, because I'm used to normal single names schemes where my first name would be a really rare catch.

Little did I know, Starcraft II actually has a two name scheme now my username is lame because it's "name (name lastname)"

Are there any options other than just buying a new copy of the game?

Comment: On the "name (name lastname)" scheme, if your name is Chandler Bing and you chose your username as "Chandler", then what you see may be "Chandler (Chandler Bing)" That's just a display for you and your real ID friends. People you see in game will see you as "Chandler".

Comment: Also, Just because you got "Chandler" doesn't mean that no one else has that name. If you hover over your portrait on the main menu, you'll see a (3 digit) code like "123" that is kinda like a last name. If two different people chose "Chandler" they'd just have different character codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you can't, according to [this GameSpot Forums thread](http://www.gamespot.com/pc/strategy/starcraft2/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-55757705&pid=939643).  I think they have the right idea - email Blizzard. It seems completely ridiculous that this feature isn't in the game. If a lot of people email them, perhaps they will implement it.

Comment: Historically, blizzard does not like you changing your name.  You can't change the Real Name on your account.  You can't change your Account name.  In Wow, you can't change your character name normally, but you can pay to transfer to a server which already has your character name taken and then change your name.  So I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: @tzenes WoW does currently have a name change paid option. It's slightly cheaper than transferring to a new server. It also comes included with the gender change, and race change option

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of what McKay said - WoW allows you to change various things about your character for a fee.

Comment: @Michael Herold - Yes, WoW allows that, but such options are not yet available for SC2. It wouldn't be surprising if they added that in the future, but they haven't yet. The question is essentially "How can I change my name now"

Comment: Hence the suggestion of emailing them to get them to implement it.  I answered the question and gave a path for future action.

Comment: @McKay ah, that must be after my time.

Comment: What a terrible idea on Blizzards part

Comment: I would suggest moving the correct answer to @McKay's, in light of the fact that there will (eventually) be a way to have this done, which makes their's the actual correct answer.

Answer (score 12):

Blizzard announced that they will allow character name changes. They plan on offering the change for free, and then later a paid service to change the name if you so desire:

http://sc2armory.com/forums/topic/18620